# Getting NameError when trying to "rename" a method with property function, and the method was defined

Tags: python

I'm reading a book on python and it says I can redefine the name of a method with the built-in "property" to call the method I renamed without having to use parenthesis at the end of the call. Said that, I tried to do it but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    Verdura.calorie = property(calcolaCalorie(self))
NameError: name 'calcolaCalorie' is not defined
```

now the code I wrote was:

```
class Cibo:
    """un esempio di classe per gestire cibi"""
    def __init__(self, proteine = 0, carboidrati = 0, grassi = 0):
        self.proteine = proteine
        self.carboidrati = carboidrati
        self.grassi = grassi

    def calcolaCalorie(self):
        return (self.proteine*4 + self.carboidrati*4 + self.grassi*9)


class Verdura(Cibo):
    def __init__(self, proteine=0, carboidrati=0):
        Cibo.__init__(self, proteine, carboidrati, grassi=0)
```

The problem reveils itself after running this code and trying to do the following thing:

```
Verdura.calorie = property(calcolaCalorie)
```

I tried to see if it was a typing error, but obviously wasn't.

Comment: You do not refer the method of the class but imply that there is a free function `calcolaColarie()`. Try `Verdura.calorie = property(Verdura.calcolaCalorie)`!

Comment: Are you looking for the `@property` decorator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python

Answer (score 0):

To copy the function you can use

```py
Verdura.calorie = Verdura.calcolaCalorie
```

Then use it like

```
v = Verdura(2,2)
v.calorie()
# ouputs 16
```

Note that I don't really see the point of doing this as your could use `calcolaCalorie()` directly and have the same result like so:

```
v = Verdura(2,2)
v.calcolaCalorie()
# ouputs 16
```

Answer (score 0):

`calcolaCalorie` is a method of your Cibo class, therefore you get the `NameError` as pointed out in the comments.

What you can do is:

```
Verdura.calorie = property(Cibo.calcolaCalorie) # or Verdura.calcolaCalorie
```

This is a way to define properties *after* you created a class.

The easier way would be to do:

```
class Cibo:
    """un esempio di classe per gestire cibi"""
    def __init__(self, proteine = 0, carboidrati = 0, grassi = 0):
        self.proteine = proteine
        self.carboidrati = carboidrati
        self.grassi = grassi

    def calcolaCalorie(self):
        return (self.proteine*4 + self.carboidrati*4 + self.grassi*9)

    @property
    def calorie(self):
        return self.calcolaCalorie()
```

This will now work for all subclasses, and if you want to change the calculation you can adjust the `calcolaCalorie` on your individual subclasses.
Similarly you could define it on Verdura only but then you need a @property on all other subclasses.